# Coding with VisualSVN SDK

Tags: vb.net, svn, visualsvn-server

Is it possible to code against the VisualSVN Server? We'd like to develop our own integrated front end for reporting / automation purposes. Our coding language will be VB.Net / C#.Net.

Any pointers to relevant documentation etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10030008/761095

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control VisualSVN Server from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017282/control-visualsvn-server-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any SVN library should be able to communicate with your VisualSVN server.

A quick Google round reveals that there are plenty of libraries for communicating with an SVN server. [SVN.NET](http://code.google.com/p/svndotnet/) beeing the first on the list.

If you don't find any libraries that you like you can always run the commandline svn client with [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for some automation and reporting with VisualSVN Server, then I have good news for you. Beginning with VisualSVN Server 3.4, the server comes with PowerShell module that provides a number of [PowerShell cmdlets for such tasks](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/). Not VB.Net or C#.Net, but should be sufficient for most admin automation tasks and report generation.