# Control VisualSVN Server from C#

Tags: c#, windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I installed VisualSVN Server 2.5.4. I can create user and repository. My question is how can I create/delete user/repository from C#. Is there any library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update 03/09/2015

There is no need to write custom WMI scripts anymore; PowerShell cmdlets available beginning with VisualSVN Server 3.4 cover the most Subversion server administration and repositories management use cases. Read about the new feature at https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/

VisualSVN Server 3.4 introduces PowerShell module that provides you with a number of helpful cmdlets. The cmdlets can be used for administering VisualSVN Server and its repositories either locally or remotely. Here is the [complete reference on VisualSVN Server PowerShell cmdlets](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/).

For example,

- You can create a new repository *MySuperRepo* by running this PowerShell command:

  `New-SvnReposiory MySuperRepo`
- You can create a project structure in the repository

  `New-SvnRepositoryItem MySuperRepo -Path /branches, /tags, /trunk -Type Folder`
- You can provide DOMAIN\Developers Active Directory group account with Read / Write access to the new repository

  `Add-SvnAccessRule MyRepo -Path / -AccountName DOMAIN\Developers -Access ReadWrite`
- You can calculate the size the repository takes on disk:

  `Measure-SvnRepository MySuperRepo`
- You can verify the repository for corruptions:

  `Test-SvnRepository MySuperRepo`

  ***And much, much more!***

For more information and the complete list of cmdlets, read the article [VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/).

---

VisualSVN Server can be managed via WMI (Windows Management
Instrumentation) interface.

MOF file which describes the VisualSVN Server interface resides in the **%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\WMI** on the computer where
VisualSVN Server is installed. Using this file as a reference you can
write a C# script to manage VisualSVN Server.

Please check the MSDN article:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394582)

I'm including the following samples for your reference:

- This C# code will create a Subversion user 'user1' with password 'secret'.

  ```
      ManagementClass userClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_User", null);

      // Obtain in-parameters for the method
      ManagementBaseObject inParams =
          userClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

      // Add the input parameters.
      inParams["Name"] = "user1";
      inParams["Password"] = "secret";

      // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
      ManagementBaseObject outParams =
          userClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
  ```
- This C# code will create a new repository 'Repo1'.

  ```
      ManagementClass repoClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_Repository", null);

      // Obtain in-parameters for the method
      ManagementBaseObject inParams =
          repoClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

      // Add the input parameters.
      inParams["Name"] = "Repo1";

      // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
      ManagementBaseObject outParams =
          repoClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
  ```
- This C# code will provide SID S-1-5-32-545 ('BUILTIN\Users') with
  Read / Write access to repository 'Test'. FYI: The AccessLevel values
  are as described in the MOF: *"0 - no access, 1 - read only, 2 - read/write"*.

  ```
  ManagementClass userClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_WindowsAccount", null);                            
  ManagementClass authzClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_SecurityDescriptor", null);
  ManagementClass permClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_PermissionEntry", null);

  ManagementObject userObject = userClass.CreateInstance();
  userObject.SetPropertyValue("SID", "S-1-5-32-545");

  ManagementObject permObject = permClass.CreateInstance();
  permObject.SetPropertyValue("Account", userObject);
  permObject.SetPropertyValue("AccessLevel", 2);

  ManagementObject repo = new ManagementObject("VisualSVN_Repository.Name='Test'");

  ManagementBaseObject inParams =
      authzClass.GetMethodParameters("SetSecurity");

  inParams["Object"] = repo;
  inParams["Permissions"] = new object[] { permObject };

  ManagementBaseObject outParams =
      authzClass.InvokeMethod("SetSecurity", inParams, null);
  ```

---

**Updated on 02/10/2013:**

WMI schema has been changed (and improved!) in VisualSVN Server 2.6. In short, to set access permissions on a repository path, you are required to:

- create `VisualSVN_Repository` class object specifying repository name,
- create `VisualSVN_PermissionEntry` entry object specifying account username and access permissions,
- invoke `SetSecurity` method on `VisualSVN_Repository` passing valid repository path and PermissionEntry object.

  ```
      ManagementClass userClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_WindowsAccount", null);
      ManagementClass permClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_PermissionEntry", null);
      ManagementClass repoClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_Repository", null);

      ManagementObject userObject = userClass.CreateInstance();
      userObject.SetPropertyValue("SID", "S-1-5-32-545");

      ManagementObject permObject = permClass.CreateInstance();
      permObject.SetPropertyValue("Account", userObject);
      permObject.SetPropertyValue("AccessLevel", 2);

      ManagementObject repoObject = repoClass.CreateInstance();
      repoObject.SetPropertyValue("Name", "MyProject");

      ManagementBaseObject inParams =
          repoClass.GetMethodParameters("SetSecurity");

      inParams["Path"] = "/trunk";
      inParams["Permissions"] = new object[] { permObject };

      ManagementBaseObject outParams =
          repoObject.InvokeMethod("SetSecurity", inParams, null);
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I am looking for. One thing is missing. how to map user and repository?

Comment: @RasedDotNet: What do you mean with 'map user and repository'?

Comment: @IvanZhakov: setup permission for a user so that s/he can only access to (one or more) specific repositories with read only/read-write permission

Comment: @RasedDotNet I've added another C# code sample which shows how to set repository access permission to a Windows account (used 'BUILTIN\Users' SID as an example).

Comment: http://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/visualsvn/0NTgU8XzbUo/NxlOcgGZqyUJ has a copy of this answer. From your profile I'm assuming you're the original author, so did Visual SVN Team copy your answer unattributed? ;)

Comment: @mafutrct The e-mail you refer to is mine (see origin of the e-mail) :) I'm VisualSVN support technician.

Comment: Haha, nice, I almost thought so :)

Comment: @bahrep, how to get the Repo URL in C#

Comment: That code maps nicely to PowerShell if you load in System.Management.dll. Thanks, you've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @bahrep Subquestion, how would you append a security entry in PowerShell? When I attempt to set more than one value to the "Permissions" parameter by using the += operator, it throws an implicit cast exception. I can post the code in a new question if that would help.