# How to add permission entries to visual svn server in C#

Tags: c#, svn, wmi, visualsvn-server

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017282/control-visualsvn-server-from-c-sharp) and got it working to create a repo and add permissions for a user using the WMI interface. The issue I am running into now is this: if I am trying to update a repo I created and add **another** user to the repo, it clears out the current use (deletes it entirely from the repo) and just adds the one person.

So, I need to figure out how to do two things:

1. Add a user to an existing repo
2. Remove a user from an existing repo

I think once I have that I will be able to figure out the rest of my interactions. I referred to the wof file and found these entries that I believe I need to implement:

**class VisualSVN_Repository**

```
[provider("VisualSVNWMIProvider"), dynamic]
class VisualSVN_Repository
    {
    [Description ("Repository name"), key]
    string Name;

    ...
    [implemented] void GetSecurity([in] string Path,
                               [out] VisualSVN_PermissionEntry Permissions[]);
    [implemented] void SetSecurity([in] string Path,
                               [in] VisualSVN_PermissionEntry Permissions[],
                               [in] boolean ResetChildren = false);
}
```

I am implementing set security like so:

```
static public void UpdatePermissions(string sid, string repository, AccessLevel level, bool isAdmin = false)
{
    ManagementClass repoClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_Repository", null);
     ManagementObject repoObject = repoClass.CreateInstance();
    repoObject.SetPropertyValue("Name", repository);

    ManagementBaseObject inParams =
        repoClass.GetMethodParameters("SetSecurity");

    inParams["Path"] = "/";
    inParams["Permissions"] = new object[] { permObject };

    ManagementBaseObject outParams =
        repoObject.InvokeMethod("SetSecurity", inParams, null);
}
```

This works, but like I said, only for one user. It seems like it cleans out anything in there and just adds the one user object.

The other method I think I need to interact with is "GetSecurity" which looks like it returns an array of VisualSVN_PermissionEntry

**VisualSVN_PermissionEntry**

```
class VisualSVN_PermissionEntry
{
    VisualSVN_Account Account;
    uint32 AccessLevel;
};
```

So this one has an AccessLevel property and VisualSVN_Account object

**VisualSVN_Account** (I am using Windows auth, so I would need to use that one)

```
[provider("VisualSVNWMIProvider"), dynamic, abstract]
class VisualSVN_Account
{
};

class VisualSVN_WindowsAccount : VisualSVN_Account
{
    [key] string SID;
};
```

So here is where I am lost. I *assume* I need to call "GetSecurity" and then iterate through those results and add them to an object array of the input parameters for "SetSecurity". I can't seem to get that to work. Some psuedo-code I have played with but am getting various errors (object reference errors mostly):

```
ManagementBaseObject inSecParams=
        repoClass.GetMethodParameters("GetSecurity");

    inSecParams["Path"] = "/";

ManagementBaseObject existingPerms =
        repoObject.InvokeMethod("GetSecurity");

//now I need to loop through the array existingPerms and add them to an array of VisualSVN_PermissionEntry object.

--or--
//can I take this result and just add the users I need to add to it somehow.
```

Comment: You can manage permissions using PowerShell cmdlets (available with VisualSVN Server 3.4 and newer): https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this awhile ago from someone at visualSVN, figured I should paste the working solution in!

Here is the whole class file that handles creation, and repository rights assignments:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;

public static class SVNManager
{
    public enum AccessLevel : uint
    {
        NoAccess = 0, ReadOnly, ReadWrite
    }

    private static ManagementObject GetRepositoryObject(string name)
    {
        return new ManagementObject("root\\VisualSVN", string.Format("VisualSVN_Repository.Name='{0}'", name), null);
    }

    private static ManagementObject GetPermissionObject(string sid, AccessLevel accessLevel)
    {
        var accountClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN",
                                           "VisualSVN_WindowsAccount", null);
        var entryClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN",
                                         "VisualSVN_PermissionEntry", null);
        var account = accountClass.CreateInstance();
        account["SID"] = sid;
        var entry = entryClass.CreateInstance();
        entry["AccessLevel"] = accessLevel;
        entry["Account"] = account;
        return entry;
    }

    private static IDictionary<string, AccessLevel> GetPermissions(string repositoryName, string path)
    {
        var repository = GetRepositoryObject(repositoryName);
        var inParameters = repository.GetMethodParameters("GetSecurity");
        inParameters["Path"] = path;
        var outParameters = repository.InvokeMethod("GetSecurity", inParameters, null);

        var permissions = new Dictionary<string, AccessLevel>();

        foreach (var p in (ManagementBaseObject[])outParameters["Permissions"])
        {
            // NOTE: This will fail if VisualSVN Server is configured to use Subversion
            // authentication.  In that case you'd probably want to check if the account
            // is a VisualSVN_WindowsAccount or a VisualSVN_SubversionAccount instance
            // and tweak the property name accordingly.

            var account = (ManagementBaseObject)p["Account"];
            var sid = (string)account["SID"];
            var accessLevel = (AccessLevel)p["AccessLevel"];

            permissions[sid] = accessLevel;
        }

        return permissions;
    }

    private static void SetPermissions(string repositoryName, string path, IDictionary<string, AccessLevel> permissions)
    {
        var repository = GetRepositoryObject(repositoryName);

        var inParameters = repository.GetMethodParameters("SetSecurity");
    inParameters["Path"] = path;

        var permissionObjects = permissions.Select(p => GetPermissionObject(p.Key, p.Value));
        inParameters["Permissions"] = permissionObjects.ToArray();

        repository.InvokeMethod("SetSecurity", inParameters, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will execute the commands needed to create a repository on the SVN server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="r">Object with the repository name.</param>
    /// <returns>True if creation was successful, False if there was a failure.</returns>
    static public bool CreateRepository(repository r)
    {
        ManagementClass repoClass = new ManagementClass("root\\VisualSVN", "VisualSVN_Repository", null);
        // Obtain in-parameters for the method
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = repoClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");


        // Add the input parameters.
        inParams["Name"] = r.name;

        // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
        ManagementBaseObject outParams =
            repoClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I think that was all the relevant code. If you see anything missing let me know and I can double check the project (it's been a month, I forgot most of this)

Comment: Here's a variation on your code in PowerShell: https://gist.github.com/sean-m/9522905  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sean_m awesome! starred that one..